# Media Player doesn't play with error code error (-38, 0) and error (-2147483648, 0)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play videos from the urls. some of them play and some of them throw this error

```
10-21 11:27:56.918: E/MediaPlayer(10809): error (-2147483648, 0)
10-21 11:27:56.918: E/MediaPlayer(10809): Error (-2147483648,0)
10-21 11:27:56.918: E/MediaPlayer(10809): pause called in state 0
10-21 11:27:56.918: E/MediaPlayer(10809): error (-38, 0)
```

The existing answers I found were a general fix for these error codes, but I am able to play some of the url videos

Code:

```
public int getCurrentPosition() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }

    }

    public void seekTo(int pos) {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
        }

    }

    public void start() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only some video, then it is not in your code, but in these videos. 
Try to use custom media players:

- [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/)
- [google/ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

Comment: This happens only in the device 2.3.3. The video plays fine on the latest Android devices. So it can be os specific issue?

Comment: Rather, the problem with the devices.

Comment: Could it because the video size is huge..one was 20 MB and it played and other was 50 MB

Comment: In older devices, not only the old system, but also a small amount of memory available.